# close all open documents after saving

Tags: javascript

I have the script partially working. 
It saves all the open psd as jpg into into a separate directory and it close some of the open files not all. 
The directory has five files. The script saves only three files, 
What am I doing wrong?

```
#target photoshop

if (app.documents.length > 0) {
//flatten the active document
app.activeDocument.flatten(); 

//jpeg options
var myJPEGOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
myJPEGOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
myJPEGOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
myJPEGOptions.matte = MatteType.WHITE;
myJPEGOptions.quality = 12;
myJPEGOptions.scans = 3;

// get documents;
var docs = app.documents;
for (var m = 0; m < app.documents.length; m++) {
app.activeDocument = docs[m];

try {
//save file to folder
var myFile = new File(("~/Desktop/forum-test") + "/" + activeDocument.name); 
app.activeDocument.saveAs(myFile, myJPEGOptions, true); 

//close the document
activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}


catch (e) {
alert ("Error the script did not execute");
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `app.documents` collection is dynamic so when you close a document this collection is changed accordingly.

Because you are closing your document inside a for loop where you compare an incrementing index against `app.documents.length` you are not processing all files (as `app.documents.length` decreases by one each time the loop is processed).

Try a while loop instead:

```
while (app.documents.length){
  // Save and close the active document here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this two lines are wrong:

```
//save file to folder
var myFile = new File(("~/Desktop/forum-test") + "/" + activeDocument.name);
```

and

```
//close the document
activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

Shouldn't you be using `app.activeDocument` instead of `activeDocument`? What is `activeDocument` anyway?

Comment: Change activeDocument to app.activeDocument in both lines and let's see what happens

Comment: I try your suggestion. Somehow the script only saves 3 files out of the 5. Is this related tot he loop?

Comment: It could be, have you tried to output (using alert or console.log) the length of app.documents (app.documents.length)? How are the documents stored in the array, are they in positions between 0 and app.documents.length-1?

Comment: I am not very fluent using the console. I will try tho. The images in the array have incremental numbers. The script is meant to function with and non consecutive file names.